# Heroku apps behind Cloudflare CDN give DNS error 1016 in Israel for around a month

Tags: heroku, dns, cloudflare

There has been an ongoing problem which at first looks like it comes from Cloudflare:

> I’m trying to use the following site:
>
> https://peakd.com
>
> If I’m on my regular internet connection at home or via my mobile phone provider here in Israel I get the following:
>
> Error 1016 Ray ID: 57eaa7fd800bad7f • 2020-04-04 11:23:24 UTC
>   Origin DNS error
>
> If I fire up a VPN and chose UK or USA the site loads properly.
>
> I am in touch with the site host but they’re not aware of any problems.

[More information on this thread at Cloudflare's community](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/getting-error-1016-on-a-site-im-trying-to-use-but-not-always/161537)

Now it turns out this happens with any Heroku hosted app or site which also uses the Cloudflare CDN.

How can we get Heroku to take a look at what is going on with DNS in Israel.

As a further data point, I cannot even get access to https://heroku.com if I'm using my Israeli ISP's DNS. Only if I use something like Cloudflare's 1.1.1.1 DNS or a VPN can I access Heroku.com.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, you can post your question over on [sf] where system and network administrators help people.

Comment: I can confirm. having the same exact problem with our site using cloudflare and heroku. We're using cloudflare ssl and have an origin certificate posted on our heroku app. I think it may be specifically related to heroku over https, because they use different domains for that rather than herokuapp.com. This is extremely frustrating and Heroku/ Cloudflare really need to fix it

Comment: I can confirm I've been getting this at random on various sites in the past couple of days.

Comment: I agree this question is probably better moved to Server Fault or Super User.

Comment: Also, I can confirm we are both using the same ISP.

Comment: I'm being led to believe now this is a network problem with Bezeq Int in Israel, one of the largest ISPs. I'm trying to find some way to get in touch with them but they are monolithic and impossible to deal with.

Comment: @BrianThomas can you describe exactly what the issue is and I'll help trying to contact them? One of our websites is also impacted by this, and I believe I can get access to their enterprise support.

Comment: I'm in the US and have the same issue. Did you find a solution?